# Continually match values to a list of keys and values in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of keys:

```
Keys=['Description of Supplier:', 'Locally Produced:', 'Imported:', 'Female Managed:', 'Female Owned:', 'Closest Landmark:', '% National Staff:', '% International Staff:', 'Operating since:', 'Previous Name:']
```

I am looping over several web pages to retrieve the contents of the table as a dictionary of values and keys:

```
webpage1={'Description of Supplier:': 'Hardware, farm tools, articles for office and school supplies (Quincaillerie, outils agricoles, articles pour bureau et articles scolaires)', 'Female Owned:': 'NO', 'Operating since:': '01/1990', 'Female Managed:': 'NO', '% National Staff:': '100', 'Locally Produced:': '100%', 'Previous Name:': ''}

webpage2={'Description of Supplier:': 'Produce, foods', 'Female Owned:': 'YES', 'Operating since:': '1987', 'Female Managed:': 'NO', '% National Staff:': '80', 'Locally Produced:': '100%', 'Previous Name:': 'Kshop'}
```

I want to combine the dictionaries by the keys:

```
newdict={'Description of Supplier:': ['Hardware, farm tools, articles for office and school supplies (Quincaillerie, outils agricoles, articles pour bureau et articles scolaires)','Produce, foods'], 'Female Owned:': ['NO','YES'], 'Operating since:': ['01/1990','1987'], 'Female Managed:': ['NO','NO'], '% National Staff:': ['100','80'], 'Locally Produced:': ['100%','100%] , 'Previous Name:': ['','kshop']}
```

However the values have to be in the right order ( I am writing them to a csv file).

I am stuck on how to do this in the most efficient way. Any suggestions? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

newdict = defaultdict(list)
for webpage in (webpage1, webpage2):
    for key, value in webpage1.items():
        newdict[key].append(value)

newdict = dict(newdict)
```

---

`newdict`:

```
{'% National Staff:': ['100', '80'],
 'Description of Supplier:': ['Hardware, farm tools, articles for office and school supplies (Quincaillerie, outils agricoles, articles pour bureau et articles scolaires)',
                              'Produce, foods'],
 'Female Managed:': ['NO', 'NO'],
 'Female Owned:': ['NO', 'YES'],
 'Locally Produced:': ['100%', '100%'],
 'Operating since:': ['01/1990', '1987'],
 'Previous Name:': ['', 'Kshop']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [webpage1, webpage2]
newdict = {}
for currentDict in data:
    for k, v in currentDict.items():
        newdict.setdefault(k, [])
        newdict[k].append(v)
print newdict
```

**Output**

```
{
    'Description of Supplier:': ['Hardware, farm tools, articles for office and school supplies (Quincaillerie, outils agricoles, articles pour bureau et articles scolaires)', 'Produce, foods'],
    'Female Owned:': ['NO', 'YES'],
    'Operating since:': ['01/1990', '1987'],
    'Female Managed:': ['NO', 'NO'],
    '% National Staff:': ['100', '80'],
    'Locally Produced:': ['100%', '100%'],
    'Previous Name:': ['', 'Kshop']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [`collections.defaultdict` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

webpage_info = defaultdict(list)

for webpage in webpages:
    # collect information on each key:
    webpage_info[specific_key].append(value_for_this_webpage)
```

The lists maintain order here, and you end up with your desired structure: values *per key*, stored in an ordered list by order of webpages visited.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of webpages where each webpage is a `dict` type object,

```
newdict = {}

for key in key_list:
    value_list = [webpage[key] for webpage in webpage_list if key in webpage]
    if value_list:
        newdict[key] = value_list

print newdict
```